# VBA equivalent for "Refresh this connection of Refresh All"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Excel enables by default the "Refresh this connection of Refresh All" setting for its connections.
Can I programmatically turn it off and on for connections?

I basically need something not made up like **RefreshOnAll** in the following example:

```
For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    If cn.RefreshOnAll Then
        cn.RefreshOnAll = False
    End If
Next
```

[image]

Comment: I can't confirm this at the moment, but this I likely a registry item.  There's a way to get at the registry through VBA though.

Comment: Then why is it part of the file's settings and moves with it between computers?

Comment: Yeah, I looked further into it and didn't find anything registry related.

Comment: @LWC I see you flagged this for migration to [SO]. VBA is sort of a grey area. Since you already got an answer on SU I don't think it necessarily has to be moved, but if you want it moved to SO I can do that.

Comment: Your choice, just wanted to make sure I keep the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code (**True** or **False**):

> ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").RefreshWithRefreshAll =
>   False

Also, if you want to prevent users from refreshing a connection, you could set the **.EnableRefresh** property (True or False)

Comment: I just want to do what the GUI setting states - removing specific connections from being part of the "Refresh All" button.

Comment: Edited to offer solution - use .RefreshWithRefreshAll property for the Connection